# Composer: scan only tag names, not the entire composer.json

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I use composer mainly to manage git repositories (both local and remote). Composer reads every tagged instance of composer.json in all historical commits:

```
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.0)
Importing tag v1.0.0 (1.0.0.0)
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.1)
Importing tag v1.0.1 (1.0.1.0)
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.2)
Importing tag v1.0.2 (1.0.2.0)
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.3)
Importing tag v1.0.3 (1.0.3.0)
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.4)
Importing tag v1.0.4 (1.0.4.0)
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.5)
Importing tag v1.0.5 (1.0.5.0)
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.6)
Importing tag v1.0.6 (1.0.6.0)
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (1.x)
Importing branch 1.x (1.x-dev)

...etc
```

It takes ages for larger repositories. Additionaly it causes a problem with github (https://circleci.com/docs/composer-api-rate-limit)

If I understand rightly, the purpose of that is to extract the version number from each composer.json file. It would be a lot quicker if composer picked the right version by reading just the tag name. Requesting `"tomekwi/composer-installers": "~1.0"` could look like this:

```
Reading tags of tomekwi/composer-installers
  - Picked matching tag (v1.0.6)
Reading composer.json of tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.6)
  - Installing tomekwi/composer-installers (v1.0.6)
```

..and take half a second instead of half a minute.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer does not know what package is inside the repository. So it has to read the `composer.json` to find out.

And because software can get renamed, there is no guarantee that every tag found in the repository belongs to the same package name.

You should take a look at hosting your local instance of Packagist, or Satis. These tools scan your repositories and grab the info needed for Composer to work. Satis might also dump the found tag into a ZIP file, which also speeds up the installation process (unzipping a downloaded file from a local server is usually faster than cloning the repo).